# I can't get some jQuery to work in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

So I have problem in jquery for safari browser. Some of my jquery is perfectly working for GC, FF, IE and Opera but then when I tried to test it in Safari my jquery is not working anymore.

My questions is:

Is there any code that I will just paste or add in my website that will enable all my jquery in safari? Currently I'm re-program my jquery because of safari. Any suggestion beside in codes. Already tried to enable the javascript and jquery in safari browser but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have turned on javascript on the safari. I can't see any other reason for it to not work , it is just a javascript file.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i already tried that. So i will just re-code it?

Comment: I don't exactly know but moderniser.js can check if the browser supports a feature or not

Comment: Altenatively you can try to copy-paste jquery code in <script></script> tag in you html file instead of linking it.

Comment: my jquery code is between  <script></script> tag im not linking it. I'll try the one you told me "moderniser.js " to help me to check what is supported